# Jquery call a function at every two characters change of an input

Tags: jquery

I try to call a function every time the user types two characters in an input, this function retrieves the value of the input and sends it as parameter of an ajax call

So how can i call the function every time the user types two characters ?

Comment: That's nice, what's the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have neither asked a question nor posted the code you would ask it about.

Comment: oh sorry, the question is how to call the function every time the user types two characters ?

Comment: handle the "input" event. Keep a count of how many times the event has occurred. If the current count is a multiple of two, then send the request.

Comment: Every time you press a second key? Or every time there are an even number of characters in the input? (E.g. What does pressing: `a` `backspace` `b` `c` do?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a global variable that keeps track of the number of times the `onkeyup()` event occurred and then call the function that sends data via `ajax` while passing in the value of the textfield.

```js
var keysPressed = 0;

$( "#inputText" ).keyup(function() {
  keysPressed++;
  if(keysPressed == 2) {
    keysPressed=0;
    let input = $( "#inputText" ).val();
    sendToAjax(input);
  }
});

function sendToAjax(input) {
  console.log(input);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="inputText" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "keyup" and get the value of the input on change. Example

```js
$( "#input" ).keyup(function() {
var input = $( "#input" ).val();

  if(input.length >= 2) {    
    $( "#result" ).text(input);      
  } else {
    myFunction();
  }
});

function myFunction(){
   $( "#result" ).text("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="" id="input" />

<p id="result"></p>
```